# Options not getting highlighted

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a multiple select options and select all button. When clicked on select all button then all options should get highlighted. However, in my case when clicked on select all button then I am getting all the options as selected and it's values but the options are not getting highlighted.

Here's my controller code.

```
$scope.selectedAll = function(){
    $scope.user.profile = []; 
    angular.forEach($scope.userprofiles, function(item){
        $scope.user.profile.push( item.profile);
    }); 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="label_hd">Profiles
    <input type="button" 
           id="select_all" 
           ng-click="selectedAll()" 
           name="select_all" 
           value="Select All">
</div>
<select multiple 
        class="browser-default" 
        name="userprofile" 
        id="userprofile"
        ng-model="user.profile">
    <option ng-repeat="profile in userprofiles"
            value="{{profile.profile}}">
            {{ profile.profile_name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Could you make an example on stackblitz? https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/MSclavi/zybnjpot/12/

You were on the right path. Instead of using a `ng-repeat` with your options, use `ng-options`. Here is the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions. Good luck